# tracing all SQL queries which have executed when application fire an order

Tags: oracle, database-performance, database-administration, database-partitioning

I need to collect all the SQL queries (SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT) which have been used by the application when any order is processed through the application.

If I can get all SQL's for atleast 50 orders processed through the application then I can check that which SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE statements are frequently in use and which tables are being frequently used by the application after finding these information.

I can get to conclusion that on which table I can use partitioning as if I get the whole SQL's with the WHERE clause I can also get to know that which type of partitioning will be better for any particular table and the partitioning.

However it seems to be a hectic exercise as there could be lots of SQL's which the application use but it helps me understand the application and also after this exercise i will be having a scrutiny report of my application behavior with database which can be used by the later employees.

For this till now i have used the DBMS_adivsor package which gives me some tables of my database to be partitioned and when i check the EXPLAIN PLAN of SQL which i used in the DBMS_ADVISOR then it occur to me that tables which are being full table scan in EXPLAIN PLAN the DBMS_ADVISOR told me to partition them.

The thing is that i can not partition the tables based on this information as its a application level partitioning and also my manager will be not convinced by this little information. so i have come up with the ABOVE plan:(

I need to do this to find out the tables where i can perform table partitioning and other performance tuning things like creating index's as i can get the where clause with filter so its like a database tuning and i want to do this as it will help me grow my career in database development.

Please help me out with this scenario.

Will this query give me required information !

```
select st.command 
  from V$SQLTEXT_WITH_NEWLINES st, SYS.V_$SQL s 
 where st.hash_value = s.hash_value
   and parsing_schema_name = 'NETSERVICOS2CM'
   and s.module = 'JDBC THIN CLIENT';
```

Tracing for non-dba USER's ----

```
GRANT SELECT ON SYS.V_$SESSION TO USER;

GRANT SELECT ON SYS.V_$MYSTAT TO USER;
```

To get the SID and SERAIL#

```
SELECT sid, serial# FROM SYS.V_$SESSION

WHERE SID = (SELECT DISTINCT SID FROM SYS.V_$MYSTAT);
```

Then on DBA user execute this --

```
EXEC DBMS_SYSTEM.SET_SQL_TRACE_IN_SESSION (sid=>3002,    serial#=>31833,sql_trace=> true);
```

OR

on no-dba user i am using --

```
ALTER SESSION SET SQL_TRACE = TRUE;
```

OR

```
EXEC DBMS_SESSION.set_sql_trace(sql_trace => TRUE);
```

Trigger to trace a session for a particular user ----

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ON_MY_SCHEMA_LOGIN
AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE
WHEN ( USER = 'NETSERVICOS1CM' )
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET TRACEFILE_IDENTIFIER = "net1cm"';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter session set statistics_level=ALL';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter session set events ''10046 trace name context     forever, level 12''';
 EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
   NULL;
 END;
```

After that to stop trace i am using

```
 ALTER SESSION SET EVENTS '10046 trace name context off';

 ALTER SYSTEM SET EVENTS '10046 trace name context off';
```

As suggested by Derek.

After this you may have multiple trace files to make a consolidate trace file we can use TRCSESS utility --

```
trcsess output=net1cm_trcsess.trc module="JDBC Thin Client" *net1cm.trc
```

It will create a single trace file net1cm_trcsess.trc for all trace file generated in my case (with trace file identifier net1cm).

Now we can use TKPROF utility to generate a report which is in human readable form using below command for example ---

```
tkprof net1cm_trcsess.trc OUTPUT=net1cm_trcsess.txt EXPLAIN=netservicos1cm/netservicos1 SYS=NO
```

Thanks

Comment: you can use SQL Profiler

Answer (score 1):

So here is my advise.

You can use several different traces for application context actions, such as INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE, SELECT, or even all actions.

Say you have a PL/SQL program run by an application, or have an OCI call to the database.  You would have this oracle code at the module/stored proc level:

```
dbms_application_info.set_module(<module_name>,'execute');
```

before you execute the entire code. (After the BEGIN in the code).

or

```
dbms_application_info.set_module(<module_name>,'UPDATE');
```

before you do an update SQL statement.

To turn off application context, you would use (before the END;):

```
dbms_application_info.set_module(NULL,NULL);
```

Then when you execute the module or run the update statement you would like to trace in the module you would make sure you did this prior to and after the module runs

```
execute DBMS_MONITOR.SERV_MOD_ACT_TRACE_ENABLE( -
service_name => '<service_name>', -
module_name => '<module_name>', -
action_name => DBMS_MONITOR.ALL_ACTIONS, -
waits => TRUE, -
binds => TRUE);
```

All actions would be traced and you would know exactly where the statement ran and what action was executed.

To turn it off:

```
execute DBMS_MONITOR.SERV_MOD_ACT_TRACE_DISABLE( -
service_name => '<service_name>', -
module_name => '<module_name>', -
action_name => DBMS_MONITOR.ALL_ACTIONS);
```

To do this at the session level, you would do the following when 9 is the serial number and 100 is the Sid, for example. (check the syntax).

```
execute DBMS_SYSTEM.SET_SQL_TRACE_IN_SESSION(9,190,TRUE);
```

To turn it off:

```
execute DBMS_SYSTEM.SET_SQL_TRACE_IN_SESSION(9,190,FALSE);
```

At the database level, (You have to be very careful with this because it will generate a trace for the entire database and can fill up your diagnostic directory on your oracle database.  Disclaimer:  USE WITH CAUTION).

```
execute DBMS_MONITOR.DATABASE_TRACE_ENABLE(waits=>TRUE, binds=>TRUE, instance_name=>'<Instance_name>');
execute DBMS_MONITOR.DATABASE_TRACE_DISABLE(instance_name=>'<instance_name>');
```

Comment: Thanks Derek for reply but i have a question here that what if there is no dbms_application_info.set_module(<module_name>,'execute'); set in our PLSQL programs ! Do i need to put them in each of our procedures, functions and packages ? and what if there is a call to only pure SQL's like SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE etc.

Comment: @Derek-- I am using execute DBMS_SYSTEM.SET_SQL_TRACE_IN_SESSION (sid=>3002, serial#=>31833,sql_trace=> true);  to race the session but i am doing this FROM a DBA user but when i tried to use it on a NON_DBA user then it gives me error for DBMS_SYSTEM package when i omit this PAKCHGE and USE ALTER SESSION SET SQL_TRACE =TRUE after granting ALETR SESSION permission to user then it dis but i am not able to locate the name of the file trace file while i can do this on a DBA user any suggestion please.

Comment: You can use the dbms_application_info.set module at the beginning and end of your stored procedures and it will context (store application session information) in the database v$sql and v$sqlarea tables.  If setting that in every stored procedure is too much work.  the you can use the DBMS_SYSTEM.SET_SQL_TRACE_IN_SESSION.

Comment: Tracing requires the DBA permission to run.  However, if you have a role such as the OEM_MONITOR and have the diagnostic pack installed on your database, you can collect the historical information from the Automatic Workload Repository with the objects DBA_HIST_SQLSTAT and DBA_HIST_SNAPSHOT table objects. You still would need to use dbms_applicaton_info in order for you to get application context, but you don't have to use tracing to collect this information in the DBA_HIST* tables.

Comment: And as I mentioned above, in the absence of tracing (which pretty much requires a DBA), you can look at the v$sql, v$sqlarea (shared-pool queries) or the DBA_HIST_SQLSTAT and DBA_HIST_SNAPSHOT tables (historical) to get all the queries that are running on the database.  Without setting the dbms_application_info in the stored procedure, you just will not know what modules they are coming from.  Anyways, let me know if you need examples from these tables.  I'll post another solution.  Regards

Comment: Thanks Derek your help is really useful for me and i am able to generate trace file for other non-dba user's also but i am doing it for session only trace as i can not do a database level trace which may generate lots of logs to read and is of NO use so now i am thinking of that how would i get to know that the application from a particular DB user using which SID and SERIAL# as i need them to use in the DBMS_SYSTEM.SET_SQL_TRACE_IN_SESSION package to start trace because my TOAD session will have different SID and SERIAL# and the APPLICATION must be using different SID and SERIAL# !

Comment: Please check the EDITED question i show the way i am doing it for tracing other user's but here my appication is TOAD.EXE in v$SESSION view now next question for me to get the SID and SERIAL# for the application from which i am going to fire the order's to track the SQL's !

Comment: No problem.  You can look at the v$session table and check the following

Comment: No problem.  You can look at the v$session table and check the following: select serial#, sid, username, module, machine, program from v$session.  But if you go into TOAD and look at what the Serial# and sid is executing.  You should be able to recognize the stored procedure.  It's difficult without application_info in the stored procedures.  But you also use the queries that are executing.  Check TOAD and the other columns in the v$session stored procedure.  I'll update my answer with an example in a hour.

Comment: Hi Derek v$session lots of SID with same module name as there are lots of other user's working !

Comment: For this i am thinking if i create a AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE trigger for the user then every time any session which i invoked by the defined user then it will start tracing as i will put the alter session set events ''10046 trace name context forever, level 12' in the trigger body. what you say will it be helpful ?

Comment: You can also join the v$session table to v$sql as well to narrow down you search.

Comment: Be careful with the 10046 flag.  It traces everything.  Make sure you turn it off after getting the information you need because it will fill up your diag directory.   Alter system set events '10046 trace name context forever, level 1';

Alter system set events '10046 trace name context off';

Comment: Using the trace flag is not my favorite method.  I prefer to use the DBMS_MONITOR.DATABASE_TRACE_ENABLE/DISABLE method.  I think the key to your solution is using query based tracing.  v$session, v$object, v$sql, v$sqlarea can help you find who is running what.  You can then use the DBMS_SYSTEM.SET_SQL_TRACE_IN_SESSION if you want to get a step-by-step execution of all the queries for that session.  If you don't need to know the exact order of execution, you can query the shared pool for all queries.

Comment: Thanks derek for the ALTER SYSTEM suggestion and i was doing the tracing so its a bit late reply to comment and going to watch soccer match so did not fing time to reply but as you suggest that to turm off 10046 then i am doing it now but i think it is giving me now the all trace's that i required. Because i am working on controlled ENV. so i am now i am tracking a user and ask him to fire order's using the application the application is also using shared pool connection so which ever session is invoked by the application for that user it will start tracing.

Comment: BUt DATABASE_TRACE_ENABLE will trace the whole database So now the trigger get invoke and start tracing for that user as the user 95% access the DB by application ONLY the (tester's).However it generates multiple .trc files which i need to consolidate using trcsess but when i use this command on even a single file then it generate blank file i do not know why i am using service name for trcsess from the .trc file in my case it is SYS$USERS it is right ? i don't why this is happening ! but i am glad now that i learn to use tracing with different methods with your help. Thanks

Comment: Please check the edited question for the trigger i am using

Comment: One more thing Derek Now i have TKPROF file with me and as i see it contains lots of information i want to understand the information in the TKPROF file is there any some helpful links on the internet or with you which you can share with me so that i can increase my understandings with oracle performance tuning meanwhile i will keep on searching for the same on internet.

Comment: Great!  Apologies for delayed response.  Glad to help.  Yeah, the SYS$USERS controls all the triggering information ans well as the tracing information, but it looks like you figured out how to use TKPROF, so that should help.  Best Wishes!

Comment: Hi Derek i did it :) and now somehow i understand the TKPROF file also but i use module name instead of service name. Thanks for your help you help me take a start with new methods.

Comment: Great!!  No problem.  You have my profile, feel free to send me a message if you have any other questions.  Best Wishes!

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage `v$sqltext_with_newlines ,V$SESSION and v$session_longops`. You can google with these words and see if these can be useful for your requirements.

Comment: will this query be of any use here ! please see edited question